# I can't add a custom font to my webpage

Tags: css

I have added the code below to my CSS but it still isn't recognised by Brackets and isn't on my page.

```
@fontface{
    font-family: swedish-sans;
    src:url(SwedenSans.otf);
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

despite my code above swedish-sans still isn't recognised in the code below.

```
.smart{

    font-family: swedish-sans, sans-serif;
    color:black;
    text-align: center;
    font-size:24px;
}
```

Comment: The property is `@font-face` and you may need to enclose your font name in quotes.

Comment: Try src:url("url");

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@font-face{ 
font-family: swedish-sans;   
src:url("SwedenSans.otf"); 
font-weight: normal; 
font-style: normal;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the help, your advice plus enclosing "swedish-sans" in quotes when calling on it worked.

Comment: No worries :) . Could you please mark it as an answer?